# Pandas Groupby year and month into columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have data in the following format

```
    LOCATION    SALESDATE   Saleprice
0   Store A 2018-04-15  524.4
1   Store B 2018-04-15  524.4
2   Store B 2018-04-15  524.4
3   Store C 2018-04-15  296.4
4   Store C 2018-04-15  296.4
```

And I want a dataframe of the following format:

```
          04/2018 05/2018 06/2018
Store A   524.4  524.4    524.4
Store B   123.2  234.4    524.4
Store C   524.4  524.4    524.4
```

Where each row is a store, and each column represents the total sales in the corresponding month/year.

I've tried:

```
df.groupby([df.LOCATION, df.SALESDATE.dt.year.rename('year'), df.SALESDATE.dt.month.rename('month')]).sum()
```

Which is almost what I want, but the 2nd and 3rd index should be columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using `pd.pivot_table()`?

I have slightly amended your code to split out month and year, so you may need to amend to get in the right format. See below:

```
df["month"] = df.SALESDATE.dt.month
df["year"] = df.SALESDATE.dt.year

new_df = pd.pivot_table(df, values="Saleprice", index="LOCATION", columns=["month", "year"])
```